# Why is there a Sephardic belief that eating seuda shelishit would in part protect you from the goings on at Gog and Magog?

Tags: sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, army-military-war, ezekiel--the-book

I read this in a siddur at a Sephardic Shul yesterday. The women around me agreed wholeheartedly with the statement, stating that it's Halacha.

I don't see the connection, other than the idea that there is a holiness to rejoicing in Shabbat, the more you eat the happier you are, therefore you are holier if you partake, and more worthy of protection. I'm not sure I care for my own personal beliefs, but I am curious how eating a meal was joined with protection from a war.

The story of Gog and Magog is in Yechezkhel 37-38.

Comment: no idea but even if it were true that doesn't make it a halacha to eat sudat shelishit b/c of the connection. It's simply ppart of the mitzvah to eat 3 meals on shabbat

Comment: @Dude that's what I thought!

Comment: it's in the talmud tractate Shabbat (118a) : “Whoever fulfills three meals on Shabbos will be saved from three tribulations: chavlei Moshiach, the judgment of Gehinom, and the war of Gog and Magog.”

Comment: As @ray pointed out the gemarah hints to this idea,however,it's regarding eating all 3 meals not just the 3rd. There are kabbalistic writings which explains so why the third meal specifically relates to being saved by gog umagog and according to some encapsulates all three meals

Comment: I don't know if anyone noticed, but it mentions 3 meals and 3 tribulations. It is possible to read the statement from the Talmud exactly as the quotation of Sephardic tradition. That the 1st meal corresponds to 'chevlei Moshiach', the 2nd meal to the judgement for Jews of 'Gehinom' and the 3rd meal to the war of Gog u'Magog. The mitzvah is that we are required to eat all 3 meals. The reason cited from Tractate Shabbat explains why. In general, Shabbat is compared to the final redemption. Each of the mitzvot associated to Shabbat would relate to details of the final redemption.

Comment: That's interesting.